# Scikit-learn encode categorical variable-length tuples

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a categorical **label (target)** called `Type` that has minimum 1-D and maximum 2-D tuple values. These are 10 examples:

```
0    (Water, Grass)
1    (Water, Grass)
2    (Water, Grass)
3             Fire
4             Fire
5     (Ice, Fire)
6            Water
7            Water
8            Water
9            Fire
```

I have tried to encode it using `MultiLabelBinarizer` but the method `fit_transform()` results in an `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. Here's how I tried to do it:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

target = ["Type"]

transformer = ColumnTransformer([("mlb", MultiLabelBinarizer(), target)],
                                remainder="passthrough")
y_transf = transformer.fit_transform(y)
```

Do I need to change the original type into something else or is there a way to keep them as they are?

Comment: I can think of 2 approaches: (1) merge tuples and code every different label to a different category (2) encode with One Hot Encoder and then use Multilabel classifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexError: tuple index out of range` means that you are not providing the function with iterable of iterables as required - see doc [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html)

convert your data into iterable of tuples. This includes conversion of 1D items like `'fire'` into `('fire',)`. Then apply `MultiLabelBinarizer()`:

```
y = [('Water', 'Grass'),  # source data
('Water', 'Grass'),
'Fire', 'Fire',
'Ice', ('Ice', 'Fire'),
'Water','Fire']

# convert into list of tuples
y = [a if type(a)==tuple else tuple((a,)) for a in y]

# MLB
mlb  = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit_transform(y)


# result
array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

`ColumnTransformer` is not needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have:

```
df["target"]
0    (Water, Grass)
1    (Water, Grass)
2    (Water, Grass)
3              Fire
4              Fire
5       (Ice, Fire)
6             Water
7             Water
8             Water
9              Fire
Name: target, dtype: object
```

To ensure we both have tuples of strings and strings let's check:

```
df["target"][0], df["target"][4]
(('Water', 'Grass'), 'Fire')
```

Then you can do:

```
texts = df["target"].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x,tuple) else (x,))
texts
0    (Water, Grass)
1    (Water, Grass)
2    (Water, Grass)
3           (Fire,)
4           (Fire,)
5       (Ice, Fire)
6          (Water,)
7          (Water,)
8          (Water,)
9           (Fire,)
Name: target, dtype: object
```

And finally:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ohe = OneHotEncoder()
ohe.fit_transform(texts.values.reshape(-1,1)).todense()
matrix([[0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Now you can do multilabel classification with this target